# Continuous representation of sequence $\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},...\}$

Tags: real-analysis

For the purpose of performing integral calculus, I would need a simple continuous algebraic representation for a good approximation, especially with the correct asymptotic behaviour, of the form $a_n \approx f(n)$ of this sequence
$$\{a_n\} = \{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},...,\frac{1}{n-1},\underbrace{\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n}}_{n -terms}\}$$?

Comment: Do you mean a general formula like $a_n=f(n)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have included this.

Comment: $$\forall (k,n)\quad1\leqslant k\leqslant n\implies a_{\frac12n(n-1)+k}=n$$

Comment: $$a_n=\left\lceil\sqrt{n+\tfrac14}+\tfrac12\right\rceil$$

Comment: @Did: Well I wanted to use it for some some integration, so I would rather prefer some straight algebraic form, where I can just plugin some reals and get the value. (you were quicker, thank you!)

Comment: @Franky_GTH Indeed context is crucial here (what a pity there is none in your question...).

Comment: @Did: You mean like that?

Comment: $$f(n) = \frac{1}{\left\lfloor \sqrt{2n-\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor }$$ works.

Comment: Yes after using gnuplot and brain I noticed there was something wrong with Dids solution.

Comment: Indeed. Well done (and sorry for the imprecision of my first comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous function which is a good approximation for small $x$:
$$y = \frac{1}{\log_2(x) + 1}$$
A continuous function which is a good approximation for all $x$ (@Winther's idea):
$$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}$$
A non-continuous function which is exact (again @Winther's idea):
$$y = \frac{1}{\Big\lfloor \sqrt{2x - \frac{3}{2}} + \frac{1}{2} \Big\rfloor}$$
All three can be seen in comparison [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kambldqbzz).

Comment: Great! I appreciate the continuous function, since I want to plug in the $n$-th prime number and then check wether the integral goes with $n$ but thats a different story, to be continued elsewhere.

Comment: Your approximation is not a very good approximation for large $x$ (it has the wrong growth-rate). Try plotting it with $\log-\log$  axes on $[0,1000]$ and you'll see this. A good approximation is $f(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$

Comment: @Winther oh sorry, I thought your comment to the question was essentially the same as Did's idea. Edited.

Comment: Just for clarity: $\log_2(x) = log(log(x))$ or $log_2(x) = ld(x)$?

Comment: $log_2$ is the logarithm to the base 2, not the logarithm of the logarithm.

Comment: @Winther should I edit my answer with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$, or are you posting a separate answer?

Comment: @Winther By "has the wrong growth rate", do you mean "cannot be salvaged"? :) (Do you also mean "the derivative does not match what is expected"?)

Comment: What we call a "good" approximation can be a bit ambigious. I mean that the growth-rate (and therefore the approximation) is bad since $\frac{a_n}{f(n)} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ when $f(n) = \frac{1}{\log_2(n) + 1}$ while $\frac{a_n}{f(n)}\to 1$ when $f(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$. This property (that the ratio goes to $1$) is imo what consistitutes a "good" approximation in this case.

Comment: @Winther: I have included that in the question. I agree, its in any case the asymptotic behaviour I was out for, but I did not expect to necessarily having to pay the costs in form of a bad local behaviour in such a case, so I didn't mention it.